# JUnit FindById returns null pointer (Mockito)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a JUnit test for one of my services in my project but I'm getting a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION every time that I run it.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code ???

The service is that I'm trying to cover is :

```
    public City findById(Long cityId) {
        logger.info("City find by ID : {}", cityId);
        return cityDao.findById(cityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(ErrorMessageEN.NO_CITY_FOUND_IN_DB));
    }
```

The JUnit is:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CityServiceImplTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private CityService cityService;

    @Mock
    private CityDao cityDao;

    private City city = new City();
    private Region region = new Region();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        city.setId(1L);
        city.setPinCode("1234");
        city.setCityName("Mumbai");

        region.setId(1L);
        region.setRegionName("Test");

        city.setRegion(region);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void findById_SUCCESS() {
        when(cityDao.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(city));
        cityService.findById(1L);
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace of it :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.recupmespoints.api.service.impl.CityServiceImplTest.findById_SUCCESS(CityServiceImplTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Would you please provide the exception stack dump?

Comment: Information that is contained in exceptions is vital to understand what went wrong. Yes, *all* information from the exception. Just by saying you have a `NullPointerException`, you aren't giving us enough tools to help you.

Comment: I added the stack trace 
Take a look at it

Comment: I can only assume your `CityService` depends on more than just `CityDao`. In that case, [Mockito will not report any errors](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html), you just won't get anything injected in there.

Comment: No it depends only on CityDao which is a repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your test class:

- **Minor one:** You don't need to use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` and `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` together. They are basically doing the same thing.
- **Major one:** Your test class must be `public`: `public class CityServiceImplTest {...}`
- **Another major one:** You are using a JUnit 4 runner `org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner` with JUnit 5 annotation `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. I suggest sticking to JUnit 4 by importing `org.junit.Test` instead.

A Simplified version of your test in JUnit 4 would be:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CityServiceImplTest {

  @InjectMocks
  CityService cityService;

  @Mock
  CityDao cityDao;

  private City city = new City();

  @Before
  public void init() {
    city.setId(1L);
    city.setPinCode("1234");
    city.setCityName("Mumbai");
  }

  @Test
  public void findById() {
    when(cityDao.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(city));
    cityService.findById(1L);
  }
}
```

But if you want to go with JUnit 5 you have to use `@BeforeEach` and  `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CityServiceImplTest {

  @InjectMocks
  CityService cityService;

  @Mock
  CityDao cityDao;

  private City city = new City();

  @BeforeEach
  public void init() {
    city.setId(1L);
    city.setPinCode("1234");
    city.setCityName("Mumbai");
  }

  @Test
  public void findById() {
    when(cityDao.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(city));
    cityService.findById(1L);
  }
}
```

Comment: He can just replace `@Before` with `@BeforeEach` as well, to use JUnit 5 consistently (then he doesn't need `@RunWith` at all as well).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you're right but JUnit 5 might need more changes than that.

Comment: No, not necessarily. If he doesn't use any rules, that's about the only change he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try with import org.junit.Test instead of import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
As @org.junit.runner.RunWith is not from junit5

Comment: Yes you're right, but this is not the only problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: @HakanDilek I'm agree that there were few more issues there. But from points you mentioned in your response which one causing null pointer?     IMO it is same which I suggested. Please share your inputs.

Comment: Neither `org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner` or `@Before` was effective in JUnit 5 context therefore mocks were not initialized. That was the reason for the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Your `init()` method is tagged with `org.junit.Before` annotation, but the test overall is run using JUnit 5, which does not recognize the method to be invoked as part of setup procedure. Meaning `MockitoAnnotations.injectMocks` is never called as well.

If you wish to use JUnit5, you should annotate your setup with [@BeforeEach](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeEach.html), as it is an equivalent annotation from JUnit 5.

Alternatively, you can go with what other users already suggested and stick with JUnit 4 API.

The main point is - don't mix JUnit versions, even if that works, it's by accident.